# Only read array if SQL search gives results

Tags: php, mysql, database

**SOLVED **
Sorry everyone, there was something wrong in the database causing these issues.

I am trying to read info from the database. And when there are rows as a result I would like to do something. My current code is like this:

```
$sql="SELECT state FROM table_name WHERE finished=0 AND start=1";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
var_dump($result);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
```

The problem I am having now that even when there is no row with finished=0, the array still gives some rows and results.
The output of the var_dump will be something like this:

```
object(mysqli_result)#5 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(3) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(2) ["type"]=> int(0) }
```

If I analyze it right this is seen as rows and the code is still executed.
Is there an approach to prevent this? Or would you deal with this issue in a complete different way?

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: You need a `FROM` clause in your query.

Comment: Apologies, I copied my code incorrectly. The code already has a FROM statement but this does not change my question.

Comment: Try after `$result = $conn->query($sql);` to set `$rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);if($rows > 0){...}`

Comment: I think the issue is that there are already 2 rows, even if there should be no results. It says 'object(mysqli_result)#5 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(4) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(2)'.  Not sure why there are rows are none of the rows should correspond to my WHERE.

If I echo $row in your code it gives 2.

Comment: Hold on, seems like something is going wrong with setting variables; that causes the rows to appear.

Answer (score 0):

you need a FROM in your query like:

```
$sql="SELECT state FROM tablename WHERE finished=0";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
var_dump($result);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
```

Comment: Apologies I accidentally removed that when 'anonymizing' my code. My current code is already as you show it, but this will give rows as a result.

Comment: Are there records in the table WHERE finished = 0?

Comment: No, if there are no records with finished = 0 it seems like there are still rows. At least, that is my conclusion out of reading that var_dump and the fact that the code is still executed twice.